# How to present a view on top of SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

[image]

I know there is many question out there on the same topic but still I didn't get any idea or solution to make it work. How do I implement a small view on top of a scene with options as shown in image?

Comment: Just use an appropriate SKNode with well chosen subnodes...

Comment: You need to access the View Controller and add another SKView to it. Then create a scene to go in that view the same way you did for the scene you already have running.

Comment: Did you find any answers to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within your scene using spritekit nodes or you can create a UIView from your viewController and add it the viewControllers view:

something like this:

```
    // set up base view of the game
    self.baseView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(self.baseView)

    // add my skView to my baseView
    self.baseView.addSubview(skView)

    // add pause button on top or other elements
    // hide or show these as needed
    self.baseView.addSubview(self.pauseBtn)
    self.addJoySticks()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use SpriteKit itself and:

```
scene?.view?.presentScene(anotherScene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0))
```

*edit* Just to add, If any Background AVPlayers or nodes are in play, then they're all discarded when transitioning.

Comment: I tried that, presentScene replaces the current scene, what I want is, just to say that you are paused and give some buttons for replay and refresh in the same scene